# Hosting Angular 9 App under a domain name

Tags: angular

I have searched a lot for answers on hosting an angular app, I have a production build angular package which has folders like so:

[image]

I happen have a basic hosting service with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as domain, I was able to upload into the public_html folder, and was able to use the angular app.
However the url has #, meaning even the home page has a url structure like wwww.example.com/#/home, is there any way where I can at least show the home page without the #/ some thing like wwww.example.com and it shows the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to consider here:

1. Make sure your angular application is using the HTML5 location strategy: https://angular.io/guide/router#locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles
2. Make sure your hosting environment supports Single Page Applications. That means that all paths that are not mapped to physical files/api endpoints or other resources should return the same `index.html` file since they will be handled on the client side by the angular application.

Answer (score 0):

You have switched from the default [`PathLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy) to [`HashLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy). Revert this.

After you switched back to `PathLocationStrategy`, make sure, your server is set up for SPA serving; meaning all paths that do not point to existing resources, should give you your `index.html`.

Also don't forget to specify `<base href="/">`. This will make sure your routing works when the app is booted in a nested path.